# I cannot create text_general_edge_ngram field on solr

Tags: tomcat, solr, tokenize

I want to search for a field on solr and I searched a lot before writing this, my problem is I add the fieldType name block to my schema.xml, but when I try to define a field, solr gives me some error, this is my fieldType code,

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and those are the fields that I am trying to add to schema.xml

```
<field name="name" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="edgengram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general_edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I am newbie to solr any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: What Solr are you using? 4.0? 3.6?

Comment: Can you add the error you are seeing to the question. Also have you examined the logs for the container you are running Solr within to see if they provide any additional details?

Comment: I am getting error because I cannot find the exact field name, so do you know the name of field name ? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question, I see the problem. You cannot have four fields all with the same name. If you really need all four fields you have defined above, I would change them to the following:

```
 <field name="name1" type="edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="name2" type="edgengram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="name3" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 <field name="name4" type="text_general_edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The actual name of the field in the schema file must be unique.

Comment: no I mean I tried all of them :) but thank you for your answer :)